# When I click the button ajax fonksyonu my trigger but does not trigger my click event to button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.9/themes/start/jquery-ui.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[id*=btnSorgu]+[Onclick*=btnSorgu_Click").live("click", function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "",
            width: 1000,
            height: 300,
            buttons: {
                Close: function () {
                    $(this).dialog('kapat');
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Function as described above.

```
<asp:Button OnClick="btnSorgu_Click" ID="btnSorgu" Text="Sorgula" runat="server" />
```

My problem is; When I click the button ajax fonksyonu my trigger but does not trigger my click event to button.

I tried to solve in this way, but did not

```
$("[id*=btnSorgu]+[Onclick*=btnSorgu_Click").live("click", function ()

$("[id*=btnSorgu]+[Onclick*=btnSorgu_Click").live("click",OnClick, function ()
```

Comment: Why you using old jquery?? I would update that asap. Live was deprecated a long time ago :)

Comment: What is `fonksyonu` ?

Comment: @FrankerZ Asking the important questions...I simply replaced it with a profanity and the sentence worked as i would expect :)

Comment: @Furtiro But he is using .live (Again thats been deprecated to .on)  which accounts for dynamically added content. Your solution would remove that. We don't know how the button gets added.

Comment: @Botonomous You are right ! I will suppress my answer if it doesn't meets op's need :)

Comment: @Furtiro I upvote you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your button like this :

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="btnSorgu_Click()" ID="btnSorgu" Text="Sorgula" runat="server" />
```

Then write directly your function in javascript :

```
function btnSorgu_Click()
{
     $("#dialog").dialog({
        title: "",
        width: 1000,
        height: 300,
        buttons: {
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog('kapat');
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, u need to wrap all your code in

```
$(function (){

});
```

For your button click,

You can have your button like this:

```
<button id="buttonid">Click Me</button>

$("#buttonid").click(function (e){
e.preventDefault(); //prevents the default action of the button. Remove if not needed.
//event to execute when button is clicked.
});
```